# Including Resources in Debug Build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I've finished development of my application and it contains three images in different PictureBoxes.

I've added them to the application by using the drop down option on the PicureBox itself, browsing to the image i made which is stored in the folder "above" the solution folder.

If i was to copy the solution folder (Which will not include the images as they are in the folder above) to a CD, would the images still work?

I've tried on my computer quickly and it does seem to work, but i don't want to risk handing it over and it not working properly.

Also using the publishing method will not work in this case as I need to hand over the solution folder/files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pictures get embedded into your .exe file as resources when it's compiled.

If you have to hand in your source code, include the images because they will be needed to build the project. If you're handing in executables only, then the image files are not required.

Comment: They will need the source code too, i'll be sure to include my images as well.

Answer (score 0):

No. You would need to include the images in the same relative location on the CD.

Here's another alternative for including images in your release. [Embedding Image Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984367(VS.71).aspx)